csv column colors in Vim 9
I just upgraded Vim to version 9.1 (under Windows). Seems now it improved the display of csv files, commas are shown as vertical lines (|), and the columns are displayed alternatively as yellow and cyan background.
Is there a way to change the coloring?
For example, I have csv files with many columns, so I would like to have 10 colors for columns to rotate.

I can't reproduce the behavior you mention without a plugin.
The csv.vim plugin provides the behavior you describe in the introduction of your question.

This plugin use only four colors (two for the header and two for the body):
hi CSVDelimiter guifg=#616E88 guibg=#2E3440

hi CSVColumnEven guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#434c5e
hi CSVColumnOdd guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#2E3440

hi CSVColumnHeaderEven guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#434c5e
hi CSVColumnHeaderOdd guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#2E3440

The rainbow_csv plugin provide the behavior you would like to have.

This plugin use an arbitrary number of colors (I use ten):
let g:rcsv_colorpairs = [
  \ ['magenta', '#B48EAD'],
  \ ['red', '#BF616A'],
  \ ['lightred', '#D08770'],
  \ ['yellow', '#EBCB8B'],
  \ ['green', '#A3BE8C'],
  \ ['cyan', '#8FBCBB'],
  \ ['lightblue', '#88C0D0'],
  \ ['blue', '#5E81AC'],
  \ ['grey', '#616E88'],
  \ ['NONE', 'NONE']
  \ ]


I did install some csv plugins in vim 8 but they didn't work. Now it seems somehow some started working in vim9. Let me check.
